# hätte, würde, könnte

Tags: grammaticality, subjunctive, standard-german

Ich habe vor kurzem ein Video von Felix von der Laden geschaut, das *„Ich hätte das Rennen gewinnen können“* heißt und dann habe ich mich gefragt, wieso hat er es genau so geschrieben?

Weil er auch *„Ich würde das Rennen gewinnen können“* und *„Ich könnte das Rennen gewinnen“* schreiben könnte.

Also meine Frage ist, was ist der Unterschied zwischen *hätte*, *würde* und *Konjunktiv II*, also in diesem Fall *könnte*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ich hätte das Rennen gewinnen können, wenn ich nicht so langsam gefahren wäre.
>
> Ich hätte das Rennen gewinnen können, wäre ich nicht so langsam gefahren.

Das ist eine Betrachtung einer hypothetischen Vergangenheit aus der Gegenwart.

> Ich würde das Rennen gewinnen können, wenn ich nicht so langsam fahren würde.
>
> Ich könnte das Rennen gewinnen, würde ich nicht so langsam fahren.

Das ist eine Betrachtung einer hypothetischen Zukunft aus der Gegenwart.

Answer (score 2):

> Ich hätte das Rennen gewinnen können

bedeutet einfach, dass es zum Zeitpunkt des Rennens möglich gewesen wäre, jetzt aber nicht mehr, da das Rennen eben vorbei ist. *Ich würde ... können* und *Ich könnte ...* beziehen sich auf aktuelle oder zukünftige Rennen, nicht aber auf vergangene.

Und da er es schon geschrieben hat, müsste Dein zweiter Satz in der Frage auch heißen:

> Weil er auch "Ich würde das Rennen gewinnen können" und "Ich könnte das Rennen gewinnen" hätte schreiben können.

:-)

Comment: Und nicht "weil er es schreiben können hätte"? Weil ich dachte, hätte sei das erste Verb und deswegen sollte es am Satzende stehen.

Comment: Und wie wäre es mit "Ich könnte das Rennen gewinnen haben"?

Comment: @Beta Wenn, dann so etwas wie: _Ich könnte das Rennen gew**o**nnen haben, weiß es aber nicht genau._

Comment: @YuraKharambura Nein, die Wortstellung in diesem Fall ist "weil ... hätte [Verb]".

Comment: @Beta Nein, das ist falsch. Es muss "gewonnen" heißen.